# JavaFX How to drag object along given SVG path - Like a slider

Tags: svg, javafx, slider, javafx-2, javafx-8

I want to drag a circle or pane along a given SVG path in JavaFX. It should work like a slider. So if the circle is at the beginning of the path, the "slider" should return 0, if the user drags the circle to the end, the "slider" should return 100.

See the attached graphic:
[Link to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mRsEz.png)

The path should be any SVG path with a beginning and an end.

I found this example but I'm not able to "convert" it to JavaFX.

[Link to example](http://codepen.io/MAW/pen/aOzeNR)

```
var D = document.createElement('div');
TweenMax.set('svg',{overflow:"visible"})
TweenMax.set('.knob',{x:10,y:80})

var tl = new TimelineMax({paused:true})
.from("#path2",1,{drawSVG:"0%",stroke:'orange',ease:Linear.easeNone})
.to('.knob',1,{bezier:{type:"quadratic",values:[{x:10,y:80},{x:150,y:0},{x:300,y:80}]},ease:Linear.easeNone},0);

Draggable.create(D,{trigger:".knob",
type:'x',
throwProps:true,
bounds:{minX:0,maxX:300},
onDrag:Update,
onThrowUpdate:Update});   
function Update(){tl.progress(Math.abs(this.x/300))};

TweenMax.to('#path1',0.5,{strokeDashoffset:-10,repeat:-1,ease:Linear.easeNone})
```

I appreciate any help.
Thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this very useful example from Jörn Hameister, who uses the Apache Batik Library to parse an SVG path.
[JavaFX - Alien Rallye with SVGPath and PathTransition](http://www.hameister.org/JavaFX_SVGPath.html)

With his JavaFXPathElementHandler I was able to convert the SVG path into a JavaFX path.

I created a path animation with a lengt of 500 seconds. All positions (x,y) of the circle - which is moving along this path - are saved within an array.

When the circle is dragged, a function searches the point with the shortest distance to the mouse within the array. The index of this position is the time (in seconds) within the animation which is then shown.

This solution works fine for me. Maybe there is a lot of optimization potential but in my case it was sufficient.

You will need the following libraries:
batik-parser.jar
batik-util.jar

They cand be found here:
[Apache Batik Library](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.xmlgraphics)

**SVGPathSlider.java**

```
package svgpathslider;

import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javafx.animation.PathTransition;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Point2D;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.scene.shape.Path;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

import org.apache.batik.parser.PathParser;


public class SVGPathSlider extends Application {

    private final static double WIDTH = 1488;
    private final static double HEIGHT = 840;

    private final static int SLIDER_MIN = 0;
    private final static int SLIDER_MAX = 100;

    private final static double ANIMATION_DURATION = 500.0d;

    private double _initX;
    private double _initY;
    private Point2D _dragAnchor;

    private PathTransition _pathTransition;
    private Circle _circle;

    private List<Point2D> _pathPointList;

    private int _actIndex;

    private int _sliderIndex = 0;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Pane root = new Pane();

        // Parse the SVG Path with Apache Batik and create a Path
        PathParser parser = new PathParser();
        JavaFXPathElementHandler handler = new JavaFXPathElementHandler("track");
        parser.setPathHandler(handler);

        // SVG Path
        parser.parse("M1411.789,59.381c-32.315,6.982-60.416,21.861-85.014,43.752c-19.922,17.731-35.061,38.869-45.943,63.058\n" +
"       c-5.333,11.853-9.46,24.204-12.018,36.946c-1.175,5.859-2.027,11.836-2.615,17.849c-0.784,8.039-1.604,16.047-1.405,24.125\n" +
"       c0.544,22.257,4.783,43.825,12.943,64.524c3.956,10.034,8.61,19.806,13.214,29.573c10.041,21.306,20.268,42.525,30.387,63.795\n" +
"       c5.109,10.741,10.271,21.46,15.19,32.288c7.075,15.575,14.958,30.839,19.51,47.438c3.979,14.508,6.568,29.219,7.169,44.322\n" +
"       c0.331,8.324,0.435,16.646-0.246,24.884c-1.532,18.565-5.443,36.725-12.43,54.038c-8.359,20.721-19.532,39.866-34.275,56.79\n" +
"       c-11.257,12.923-24.016,24.286-38.271,33.754c-15.338,10.186-31.729,18.501-49.484,23.784c-9.592,2.853-19.303,5.104-29.216,6.816\n" +
"       c-15.327,2.646-30.695,2.349-46.054,2.007c-9.38-0.208-18.705-2.263-28.096-2.838c-6.393-0.393-12.754-1.123-19.09-1.821\n" +
"       c-8.197-0.902-16.423-1.712-24.613-2.781c-5.534-0.722-11.162-1.225-16.739-1.823c-5.861-0.631-11.759-1.022-17.578-2.167\n" +
"       c-2.655-0.522-5.449-0.437-8.188-0.75c-8.846-1.013-17.698-1.924-26.519-3.171c-5.554-0.786-11.189-0.973-16.764-1.633\n" +
"       c-7.814-0.928-15.595-2.138-23.412-3.036c-2.847-0.327-5.725-0.423-8.588-0.699c-8.938-0.864-17.943-1.748-26.899-1.554\n" +
"       c-15.911,0.347-31.625,2.248-47.251,5.876c-15.535,3.606-31.159,6.96-46.725,10.469c-14.081,3.174-28.128,6.604-42.203,9.777\n" +
"       c-16.611,3.743-33.229,7.521-49.856,11.208c-9.739,2.16-19.507,4.166-29.301,5.996c-5.747,1.073-11.674,1.388-17.537,1.594\n" +
"       c-7.402,0.261-14.82,0.113-22.231,0.052c-15.293-0.127-30.188-2.85-44.857-6.989c-21.598-6.095-40.763-16.693-58.57-30.253\n" +
"       c-27.463-20.914-55.199-41.478-83.072-61.846c-15.905-11.621-34.119-18.604-53.016-23.727c-9.574-2.596-19.33-4.402-29.226-5.603\n" +
"       c-11.292-1.37-22.576-2.289-33.947-2.248c-11.527,0.041-22.741,2.374-33.923,4.73c-11.105,2.342-22.015,5.769-33.198,7.525\n" +
"       c-9.26,1.455-18.411,3.436-27.664,4.864");

        Path path = handler.getPath();
        root.getChildren().add(path);

        // Moving image
        _circle = new Circle(20);
        _circle.setFill(Color.RED);

        root.getChildren().add(_circle);

        // Path Transition
        _pathTransition = new PathTransition();
        _pathTransition.setDuration(Duration.seconds(ANIMATION_DURATION));
        _pathTransition.setPath(path);
        _pathTransition.setNode(_circle);
        _pathTransition.setOrientation(PathTransition.OrientationType.ORTHOGONAL_TO_TANGENT);
        _pathTransition.setCycleCount(1);
        _pathTransition.playFromStart();
        _pathTransition.pause();
        _pathTransition.jumpTo("end");

        // Save the circle positions on the path
        _pathPointList = new ArrayList<>();
        savePositions();


        // Mouse presssed handler
        _circle.setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            public void handle(MouseEvent me) {
                 // Store initial position
                _initX = _circle.getTranslateX();
                _initY = _circle.getTranslateY();
                _dragAnchor = new Point2D(me.getSceneX(), me.getSceneY());                
            }
        });


        // Mouse dragged handler
        _circle.setOnMouseDragged(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            public void handle(MouseEvent me) {
                double dragX = me.getSceneX() - _dragAnchor.getX();
                double dragY = me.getSceneY() - _dragAnchor.getY();

                // Calculate new position of the circle
                double newXPosition = _initX + dragX;
                double newYPosition = _initY + dragY;

                // Get the nearest index (= second) of the animation
                _actIndex = getAnimationIndex(newXPosition, newYPosition);

                // Show animation at the given second
                _pathTransition.jumpTo(Duration.seconds(_actIndex));                                

                // Get slider index
                _sliderIndex = remap(_actIndex, ANIMATION_DURATION, 0, SLIDER_MIN, SLIDER_MAX);
                System.out.println(_sliderIndex);
            }
        });

        primaryStage.setTitle("JavaFX SVG Path Slider");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, WIDTH, HEIGHT));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }    


    /**
     * Save the position of the circle for every second of the animation in
     * a list.
     */
    private void savePositions() {

        if (_pathPointList == null)
            return;

        for (int i=0; i<=(int)ANIMATION_DURATION; i++) {
            _pathTransition.jumpTo(Duration.seconds(i));

            _pathPointList.add(new Point2D(_circle.getTranslateX(), _circle.getTranslateY()));
        }

    }

    /**
     * Returns the index 
     * @param mousePosX
     * @param mousePosY
     * @return 
     */
    private int getAnimationIndex(double mousePosX, double mousePosY) {

        int nearestIndex = 0;

        int i = 0;
        double dx;
        double dy;
        double old_dist = Double.MAX_VALUE;
        double act_dist;

        for (Point2D pathPos : _pathPointList) {

            // Get distance between mouse position and saved position on path
            // with pythagoras
            dx = mousePosX - pathPos.getX();
            dy = mousePosY - pathPos.getY();
            act_dist = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);

            if (act_dist < old_dist) {
                old_dist = act_dist;
                nearestIndex = i;
            }

            i++;            
        }

        return nearestIndex;
    }

    /**
     * Remaps the given value from one to anoter range
     * 
     * @param value
     * @param from1
     * @param to1
     * @param from2
     * @param to2
     * @return 
     */
    private int remap (int value, double from1, double to1, double from2, double to2) {
        double tmp = (value - from1) / (to1 - from1) * (to2 - from2) + from2;        
        return (int)tmp;
    }
}
```

**JavaFXPathElementHandler.java** (Author: j. Hameister)

```
package svgpathslider;

import javafx.scene.shape.ArcTo;
import javafx.scene.shape.ClosePath;
import javafx.scene.shape.CubicCurveTo;
import javafx.scene.shape.LineTo;
import javafx.scene.shape.MoveTo;
import javafx.scene.shape.Path;

import org.apache.batik.parser.ParseException;
import org.apache.batik.parser.PathHandler;

/**
 * 
 * @see PathHandler Interface
 * 
 * http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html
 * 
 * @author j.hameister
 *
 */
public class JavaFXPathElementHandler implements PathHandler {

    private Path path = new Path();

    private float lastX = 0;
    private float lastY = 0;

    public JavaFXPathElementHandler(String pathStyling) {
        path.getStyleClass().add(pathStyling);
    }

    @Override
    public void arcAbs(float rx, float ry, float xAxisRotation, boolean largeArcFlag, boolean sweepFlag, float x, float y) throws ParseException {
        lastX = x;
        lastY = y;
        path.getElements().add(new ArcTo(rx, ry, xAxisRotation, x, y, largeArcFlag, sweepFlag));
    }

    @Override
    public void arcRel(float rx, float ry, float xAxisRotation, boolean largeArcFlag, boolean sweepFlag, float x, float y) throws ParseException {
        lastX = x;
        lastY = y;

        path.getElements().add(new ArcTo(rx, ry, xAxisRotation, x, y, largeArcFlag, sweepFlag));
    }

    @Override
    public void closePath() throws ParseException {
        path.getElements().add(new ClosePath());
    }

    @Override
    public void curvetoCubicAbs(float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2, float x, float y) throws ParseException {
        lastX = x;
        lastY = y;

        CubicCurveTo c = new CubicCurveTo(x1,y1,x2,y2,x,y);
        c.setAbsolute(true);
        path.getElements().add(c);
    }

    @Override
    public void curvetoCubicRel(float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2, float x, float y) throws ParseException {
        lastX = x;
        lastY = y;
        CubicCurveTo c = new CubicCurveTo(x1,y1,x2,y2,x,y);
        c.setAbsolute(false);
        path.getElements().add(c);
    }

    @Override
    public void curvetoCubicSmoothAbs(float x2, float y2, float x, float y) throws ParseException {
        throw new ParseException("curvetoCubicSmoothAbs is currently not supported.", null);
    }

    @Override
    public void curvetoCubicSmoothRel(float x2, float y2, float x, float y) throws ParseException {
        throw new ParseException("curvetoCubicSmoothRel is currently not supported.", null);
    }

    @Override
    public void curvetoQuadraticAbs(float x1, float y1, float x, float y) throws ParseException {
        throw new ParseException("curvetoQuadraticAbs is currently not supported.", null);
    }

    @Override
    public void curvetoQuadraticRel(float x1, float y1, float x, float y) throws ParseException {
        throw new ParseException("curvetoQuadraticRel is currently not supported.", null);
    }

    @Override
    public void curvetoQuadraticSmoothAbs(float x, float y) throws ParseException {
        throw new ParseException("curvetoQuadraticSmoothAbs is currently not supported.", null);
    }

    @Override
    public void curvetoQuadraticSmoothRel(float x, float y) throws ParseException {
        throw new ParseException("curvetoQuadraticSmoothRel is currently not supported.", null);
    }

    @Override
    public void endPath() throws ParseException {}

    @Override
    public void linetoAbs(float x, float y) throws ParseException {
        lastX = x;
        lastY = y;

        LineTo lineTo = new LineTo(x,y);
        lineTo.setAbsolute(true);
        path.getElements().add(lineTo);
    }

    @Override
    public void linetoHorizontalAbs(float x) throws ParseException {
        lastX = x;
        LineTo lineTo = new LineTo(x, lastX);
        lineTo.setAbsolute(true);
        path.getElements().add(lineTo);
    }

    @Override
    public void linetoHorizontalRel(float x) throws ParseException {
        lastX = x;
        LineTo lineTo = new LineTo(x, lastY);
        lineTo.setAbsolute(false);
        path.getElements().add(lineTo);
    }

    @Override
    public void linetoRel(float x, float y) throws ParseException {
        lastX = x;
        lastY = y;
        LineTo lineTo = new LineTo(x, y);
        lineTo.setAbsolute(false);
        path.getElements().add(lineTo);
    }

    @Override
    public void linetoVerticalAbs(float y) throws ParseException {
        lastY = y;
        LineTo lineTo = new LineTo(lastX, y);
        lineTo.setAbsolute(true);
        path.getElements().add(lineTo);
    }

    @Override
    public void linetoVerticalRel(float y) throws ParseException {
        lastY = y;
        LineTo lineTo = new LineTo(lastX, y);
        lineTo.setAbsolute(false);
        path.getElements().add(lineTo);
    }

    @Override
    public void movetoAbs(float x, float y) throws ParseException {
        lastX = x;
        lastY = y;
        MoveTo moveTo = new MoveTo(x, y);
        moveTo.setAbsolute(true);
        path.getElements().add(moveTo);
    }

    @Override
    public void movetoRel(float x, float y) throws ParseException {
        lastX = x;
        lastY = y;
        MoveTo moveTo = new MoveTo(x, y);
        moveTo.setAbsolute(false);
        path.getElements().add(moveTo);
    }

    @Override
    public void startPath() throws ParseException {
    }

    public Path getPath() {
        return path;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could, instead of getting the nearest point in the list, calculate the "force" (as a vector) that the dragging action causes on the circle and see if this force brings the circle closest to the next or previous point in the list. Because just calculating the nearest point can cause a teleport on the circle, depending on the path. But if you don't mind it it's ok.

(I don't have 50 reputation to just add a comment, that's why it is an answer... sorry)